# JOIN Query ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, database, join, activerecord

I have 3 models : 
 * Technician
 * WorkContract
 * WorkContractType

I want to code a helper that do a search query to the data base and return all the data even if the shared column between the 2 joined table is nil, the helper is used in other side of the project and it work very well when i do the search

here is the user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base {
                      :id => :uuid,
                   :email => :string,
      :encrypted_password => :string,
    :reset_password_token => :string,
  :reset_password_sent_at => :datetime,
     :remember_created_at => :datetime,
           :sign_in_count => :integer,
      :current_sign_in_at => :datetime,
         :last_sign_in_at => :datetime,
      :current_sign_in_ip => :string,
         :last_sign_in_ip => :string,
      :confirmation_token => :string,
            :confirmed_at => :datetime,
    :confirmation_sent_at => :datetime,
       :unconfirmed_email => :string,
    :authentication_token => :string,
                    :type => :string,
              :company_id => :uuid,
                 :team_id => :uuid,
      :weekly_schedule_id => :uuid,
              :first_name => :string,
               :last_name => :string,
                  :avatar => :string,
                :username => :string,
                  :gender => :integer,
      :invitation_sent_at => :datetime,
             :birthday_on => :date,
             :is_archived => :boolean,
           :updated_by_id => :uuid,
               :device_id => :string,
             :import_keys => :hstore,
              :created_at => :datetime,
              :updated_at => :datetime,
            :is_localized => :boolean,
        :is_administrator => :boolean,
                :store_id => :uuid,
                    :code => :string,
   :current_session_token => :string
}
```

and here the WorkContractType model :

```
class WorkContractType < ActiveRecord::Base {
             :id => :uuid,
           :name => :string,
           :slug => :string,
    :is_archived => :boolean,
  :updated_by_id => :uuid,
      :device_id => :string,
     :created_at => :datetime,
     :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

and the last WorkContract :

```
class WorkContract < ActiveRecord::Base {
                     :id => :uuid,
                :user_id => :uuid,
  :work_contract_type_id => :uuid,
               :start_on => :date,
                 :end_on => :date,
            :is_archived => :boolean,
          :updated_by_id => :uuid,
              :device_id => :string,
            :import_keys => :hstore,
             :created_at => :datetime,
             :updated_at => :datetime,
     :rubric_category_id => :uuid
}
```

I'm calling my helper function :

```
    class TechnicianQueryHelper

  def initialize( query = nil )
    @query = Arel.sql("UNACCENT('%#{ query }%')")
  end

  def search
    Technician.joins(:work_contract_types).where(
      first_name.matches( @query )
        .or( last_name.matches( @query ) )
        .or( email.matches( @query ) )
        .or( technician_code.matches( @query ) )
        .or( work_contract_name.matches( @query ) )
    )
  end
```

when try to search a technician that not work, and when I removed the join condition it work but it not in other vue, I think there is a problem with the join condition and I thought that if I rewrite the query with left join or some thing that return all data even if nil will help ! 
note that :

> User : has_many   :work_contracts, -> { order 'start_on DESC' } and
>   has_many   :work_contract_types, through: :work_contracts
>
> WorkContract :  belongs_to :user and belongs_to :work_contract_type

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join, by default `includes` do the trick, but it rename the column.
So I suggest trying `includes` instead of `join`
If not help try:

```
 Technician.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN work_contracts ON work_contracts.user_id = users.id").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN work_contract_types ON work_contracts.work_contract_type_id = work_contract_types.id").where(
```

Comment: Hi Alexander , thanks for your answer , it does not work , maybe you need to see the models relationships to understand more 

 * User  has_many   :work_contract_types, through: :work_contracts 
 /////// WorkContract belongs_to :user, belongs_to :work_contract_type

Comment: In case you need "work_contract_type" it could be additional join:
`joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN work_contract_type ON work_contract.work_contract_type_id = work_contract_type.id")`
Also would be great to know error to analyze.
And why do you describe User class, but request is for Technician?

Comment: because Technician is inherited from User, and User is related to WorkContractType thought WorkContract

Comment: Updated the answer for your many to many
Hope there are no conflicts about table_name for Technician class or you set table_name explicitly.